# How to pass type (e.g. String) as function argument?

Tags: swift

I'm using "JSON to my own class" and I have real headache with type conversions. Typical conversion is looks like:

```
I need: "55" (JSON) -> 55 (Int)
My path: AnyObject? -> String -> Int
```

Swift isn't converting AnyObject("55") to Int("55") directly, Swift thinks that "55" is always String. So I've written helper method:

```
internal func jsonDirectToInt(from: AnyObject?) -> Int? {
    guard let string = from as? String,
        let int = Int(string) else { return nil }

    return int
}
```

**My question**: can I pass class type to function as argument, so I can write something like that:

```
internal func jsonDirectToInt(from: AnyObject?, type: <T>) -> Int? {
    guard let string = from as? String,
        let int = <T>(string) else { return nil }

    return int
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Possibly I'm misunderstanding what you want to achieve, but it sounds from your question and the third code block that follows that you want a "`jsonDirectToAnything`" generic function; attempting to convert the JSON `from` parameter to the type passed via `type` parameter, using a `JSON (AnyObject) -> String -> SomeType` pipeline. In your code example above (last code block) your return type is set to `Int` even when showing that you want some generic `<T>(string)` conversion (which is assigned to return type), so I will assume that using return type `Int` is not what you're after, but rather using a generic return type (if not; the question don't really make much sense for me).

---

Anyway, for the technical discussion: you can create such a function with the generic return type constrained to types that conform to a protocol---say `StringInitializable`---that includes a blueprint for an (failable) initializer by `String` instances. You extend the types you want to be able to use the "generic" `jsonDirect` method to `StringInitializable`, and, if needed, implement the `String` initializer blueprinted by the protocol. In the example below, I've blueprinted initializer `init?(_ text: String)` in `StringInitializable`. This failable initializer is readily natively available for e.g. `Double` and `String` types, but needs to be implemented (just as a wrapper) for e.g. extending `Int` to the protocol.

Finally note, before we proceed, that there exist several existing tools for handling conversion of JSON data to native Swift types, e.g.

- [SwiftyJSON](https://github.com/SwiftyJSON/SwiftyJSON)

---

Example solution for your specific question:

```
/* Protocol with blueprint for failable initializer by String */
protocol StringInitializable {
    init?(_ text: String)
}

/* Extend type types you want to use "generically" in 'jsonDirect' method */
extension Double : StringInitializable { } // already has a 'init?(_ text: String)', OK
extension String : StringInitializable { } // already has a 'init?(_ text: String)', OK
extension Int : StringInitializable {      // point to 'init(_:radix:)' initializer
    init?(_ text: String) {
        guard let foo = Int.init(text, radix: 10) else {
            return nil
        }
        self = foo
    }
}

/* Your own class */
class MyClass: StringInitializable {
    let foo : Int?
    required init?(_ text: String) {
        foo = Int(text)
    }
}

/* jsonDirect for (attempted) type conversion from AnyObject to 
   generic type, where the latter is constrained to types conforming 
   to protocol 'StringInitializable' */
func jsonDirect<T: StringInitializable>(from: AnyObject?, toType _ : T.Type) -> T? {
    guard let foo = from as? String, let bar = T(foo) else {
        return nil
    }
    return bar
}
```

Example usage for JSON conversion into `Int`, `Double` and `String` as well as a the custom class `MyClass`:

```
/* Example usage */
var myJSONInt : AnyObject = "55"
var myJSONInvalidInt : AnyObject = "foo"
var myJSONDouble : AnyObject = "55.3"
var myJSONString : AnyObject = "Foo"

/* Attempt json -> specified type conversions */
let fooInt = jsonDirect(myJSONInt, toType: Int.self)
let fooMyClass = jsonDirect(myJSONInt, toType: MyClass.self)
let fooInvalidInt = jsonDirect(myJSONInvalidInt, toType: Int.self)
let fooDouble = jsonDirect(myJSONDouble, toType: Double.self)
let fooIntString = jsonDirect(myJSONInt, toType: String.self)

/* Results */
print(fooInt.dynamicType, ": value =", fooInt ?? "nil")
    // Optional<Int> : value = 55

print(fooMyClass.dynamicType, ": value =", fooMyClass?.foo ?? "nil")
    // Optional<MyClass> : value = 55

print(fooInvalidInt.dynamicType, ": value =", fooInvalidInt ?? "nil")
    // Optional<Int> : value = nil

print(fooDouble.dynamicType, ": value =", fooDouble ?? "nil")
    // Optional<Double> : value = 55.3

print(fooIntString.dynamicType, ": value =", fooIntString ?? "nil")
    // Optional<String> : value = 55
```